# Estimate an integral over a set using the passage times of an independent process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, markov-process, stopping-times

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable
- $q$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ with $$\{q=0\}\subseteq\{f=0\}\tag1$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued independent process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X_n\sim q\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag2$$
- $B\in\mathcal E$ with $$c:=(q\lambda)(B)\in(0,1)\tag3$$
- $\tau_0:=0$, $$\tau_k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau_{k-1}:X_n\in B\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ and $$Y_k:=X_{\tau_k}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$

Note that $(Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is independent with $$Y_n\sim (q\lambda)\left[\;\cdot\mid B\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N\tag4.$$ Let $$g(x):=1_B(x)\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac fq(x)&\text{, if }q(x)>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E.$$ Note that $$\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^kg(Y_i)\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}(q\lambda)\left[g\mid B\right]=\frac1c\int_Bf\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{almost surely}.\tag5$$

> Say we want to use $(Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ to estimate $$I:=\int_Bf\:{\rm d}\lambda.$$ In practice, I'm independently drawing $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim q\lambda$, where $$n=\frac{n_0}c\tag6$$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$, and estimate $I$ by $$\frac1{n_0}\sum_{i=1}^ng(X_i).\tag7$$ How can we prove rigorously that $(7)$ is a sensible estimator of $I$?

We may consider the number $$N_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n1_B(X_i)$$ of visits to $B$ up to time $n$ and note that $$\operatorname E\left[N_n\right]=nc\tag8$$ and $$\frac{N_n}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}c\;\;\;\text{almost surely}.\tag9$$ Now, $(7)$ is equal to $$\frac1{\operatorname E\left[N_n\right]}\sum_{i=1}^{N_n}g(Y_i)\tag{10}.$$

> I first thought $(10)$ might tend to $I$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, but since $$\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^mg(X_i)\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}I\tag{11}$$ this cannot be true (since the $(10)$ and the left-hand side of $(11)$ are off by factor of $c$). So, does maybe $(10)$ tend to $I$ as $n_0$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: What is $h$? Is it $h= 1_B$?

Comment: @Mick Yes, sorry.

Comment: @Mick Your formula should be wrong. As mentioned in the question, $Y_k\sim(q\lambda)\left[\;\cdot\mid B\right]$ and hence $\operatorname E\left[g(Y_i)\right]=(q\lambda)\left[g\mid B\right]=c^{-1}I$. So, you're off by a factor of $c^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I overlooked that $X_{\tau_k} \in B$...

Comment: Actually $\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_n} g(Y_i)$. So $\frac1{cn} \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i)$ converges to $\frac1c \int_B f\ d\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wald's lemma, if $N$ is a nonegative integer valued random variable with $EN <\infty$ and $X_n$ is an iid process, then under some not too restrictive conditions
$$ E[ \sum_{i=1}^N X_i] = EN EX_1, $$
hence 
$$E\bigg[ \frac1{EN_n } \sum_{i=1}^{N_n} g(X_i)\bigg] = Eg(X_1) = \int_B fd\lambda$$
Then you can apply SLLN, since the the process $g(X_i)$ is iid and the expectation is finite. 
Actually you don't necessarily need the $Y_i$'s, since your $g$ takes care of the case when $X_i\notin B$. 
$$ E[g(X_i)] = \int_B f d\lambda$$ so due to the SSLN
$$ \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) \to \int_B fd\lambda\quad a.s. $$
Note that 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_n} g(Y_i) $$ 
hence
$$ \frac1{nc} \sum_{i=1}^n g(Y_i) \to \frac1c \int_B f\ d\lambda$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please note that (unfortunately) this is not the result I'm looking for. It's clear to me that $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^ng(X_i)\to I=\int_Bf\:{\rm d}λ$ a.s., since $(X_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ is an ergodic time-homogeneous Markov process with stationary distribution $q\lambda$. The problem with the estimator $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^ng(X_i)$ is that, if $B$ is a "small" set, most of the $X_i$'s won't contribute to the sum. I think that I'm somehow confused by my $n$'s and $n_0$'s. I guess that what I need to show is that $(10)$ tends to $I$ as $n_0$ (*not* $n$) tends to $\infty$.

Comment: See my last comment just after your question

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Everything you've written is correct. However, as described in the question, my actual concern really is to show that $(7)$ (hence $(10)$) is a sensible estimator (tends to $I$ as $n$ or $n_0$ tends to $\infty$).

Comment: There is something I don't understand here then... so you would like to show that $\frac{1}{EN_n} \sum_{i=1}^{N_n} g(Y_i) = \frac{1}{nc} \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) $ converges to $\int_B f\ d\lambda$ ? This is not going to happen since this converges to $\frac1c \int_B f\ d\lambda$... Or I really misunderstood something... The question is interesting so I'd do like to understand it.

Comment: Yes, there something I don't understand neither. I've done all the calculations you've made before. I don't think it's application-specific, but I've noticed the estimator you've suggested is not working (while $(7)$ is) in a specific application. I've asked a corresponding question with all the details here: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/9589/9254. Maybe you can take a look even when you're not familiar with the application.

Comment: Okay, we agree that the maths is good. Looking at the link you mentioned earlier the first thing that comes to my mind is what you wrote there too: namely that somehow $\int_B f d\lambda$ is really small (either because of $B$ being small or $f$ being small, or $\lambda$) and upscaling it by the inverse of the measure of $B$ (which is also small) gives you the right "answer"... meditate on this, i will...

Comment: I've accepted your answer, cause I've figured out the problem is really in the application. Essentially, $q$ was defined in a different way that I was thinking it is and the $q$ in the application was off from my $q$ precisely by a factor of $c$. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What's worrying me now is how we can generalize this to an arbitrary Markov chain (which our independent process here certainly is): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570272/47771.